# Spring Boot Microservices JUnit Test- Controller Test- JWT JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jwt, spring-cloud

I tried to implement some controller test with the usage of jwt in Spring Boot Microservices.

When I run the test method shown below, I got this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
```

Here is the code snippets shown below.

```
@Test
    public void test_WhenPlaceOrderWithWrongAccess_thenThrow403() throws Exception {
        OrderRequest orderRequest = getMockOrderRequest();
        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/order/placeOrder")
                        .with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))  // HERE IS THE ERROR LINE
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest))
                ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isForbidden())
                .andReturn();
    }
```

Even if I added `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` dependency in pom.xml of order service, It didn't help me fix the issue.

Here are the issue shown below after adding `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` dependency in pom.xml of order service.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/Jwt$Builder

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt$Builder
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the link of example : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer)

Comment: Then instead of `.with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))` use `.header("Authorization", "Bearer ")`

Comment: @kladderradatsch There are different kinds of roles like ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER for authority in the controller. Can you look through only order service?

Comment: @S.N However, I assume a 403 can be provoked when the access token is missed at all or invalid.

Comment: @kladderradatsch How can I get bearer token from auth service and use it in this test method? I also add spring-security-oauth2-jose but it didn't help me? What kind of dependencies should I use in order service?

Comment: Could you please check [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6209) here?

Comment: Do not set security headers with MockMvc. Use MockMvc post processors (like you do) or use test annotations to set Authentication instance in test security-context directly.

Comment: @kladderradatsch I already looked through the link before but my issue is different.

Comment: @kladderradatsch  I think there is a problem in security configs in order service and api gateway. Even if I tried to revised these files, I still get 403 forbidden issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: I would read meticulously [how to test JWT authentication via spring-security-test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/test.html#testing-bearer-authentication) and furthermore the tutorial of ch4mp because he seems to be a Spring developer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you only need the dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but not `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server`

Comment: I already defined these dependencies in pom.xml of order service. It didn't help me.

Comment: I changed my vision to use different approach. Here is the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449956/spring-boot-microservice-junit-test-how-to-write-a-test-method-with-adding-the

Comment: I still couldn't fix the issue. Can you help me? How can I revise security option between api gateway and order service?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` dependency is correctly declared: scope **`compile`** (must be there at `runtime` and `test`) and version **5.2 or above** (`JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` was not there before). You might pull it as transitive dependency of `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`. So basically, check that:

- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` is declared dependency for each resource-server module
- security-configuration is there for each resource-server module
- JwtDecoder is mocked for each unit-test (`@WebMvcTest`) and integration test with mocked authentication (`@SpringBootTest` with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`)

Sorry to tell you that, but your code is a mess:

- no parent pom to manage modules versions (had to manually `mvn install` modules in the right order.
- you test security rules in modules with no security configuration
- some resource-servers do not pull `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (products service for instance)
- you write integration tests (`@SpringBootTest`) to unit test controllers (should be `@WebMvcTest` with `@MockBean` dependencies)
- have to run configuration server for test to run (you should configure unit-tests to run in isolation from the rest of the world, starting with external services like cloud-config)
- ...

Cleanup your mess before asking us to look into your code.

For now, all I can tell you is to follow [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials). It covers in details resource-servers security configuration and testing. It also demoes how to use annotations in place of `jwt()` MockMvc post-processor. Annotations are more readable to me and also enable to setup security context when **testing secured services**:

```java
    @WithMockJwtAuth("ROLE_USER")
    @Test
    public void test_WhenPlaceOrder_DoPayment_Success() throws Exception {
        OrderRequest orderRequest = getMockOrderRequest();
        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/order/placeOrder")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest))
                ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        ...

    }
```

Comment: I already used 5.7.3 version. Your view couldn't help me fix the issue.

Comment: When you  use `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` in your dependencies you'll not need **spring-security** explicitly because it is contained there already. This I have from the [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-resource-server). [You](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer/blob/main/orderservice/pom.xml#L112-L115) have Spring Security still in your dependencies.

Comment: Hadn't seen your complete répo was linked, will give a try later today

Comment: @ch4mp As I guess I cannot get jwt token from auth service, I get this issue. How can I get it from auth service and use it with its role in order controller test?

Comment: You don't get a JWT at all. Test framework populates directly the security context with an Authentication instance built "as if" a JWT was decoded and validated. Clone my repo and debug the samples, you'll see.

Comment: @ch4mp JWT is coming from auth service and I use JWTFilter in API Gateway. How can I get jwt token from auth service and make a request with the bearer token to each service? This is my issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JUnit tests of a @Controller and is a complete different question. Ask it in a different thread.

Comment: @ch4mp That's why I asked it as a new question. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74445207/spring-boot-microservice-junit-test-how-can-i-get-jwt-token-from-one-service-a

Comment: @ch4mp I changed my vision to use different approach. Here is the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449956/spring-boot-microservice-junit-test-how-to-write-a-test-method-with-adding-the

Comment: @ch4mp  I think there is a problem in security configs in order service and api gateway. Even if I tried to revised these files, I still get 403 forbidden issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: Easy: stop believing I have not understood your problems (as mentioned in my answer, I have cloned your repo and manipulated your code and know they are quite a few different problems) or that I don't know what I'm talking about, and just follow (carefully) the tutorials I pointed you to, 3 times already. You'll get a chance to understand how to configure and test a resource-server (micro-service or not)

Comment: @ch4mp I still couldn't fix the issue. Can you help me? How can I revise security option between api gateway and order service?

Comment: No, I can't help you: you don't explain you problems clearly enough and don't read the answers